# Is there a standard for testing Mumps?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, mumps

We need to be able to execute automation testing of Mumps code as a business requirement.

Is this possible? Any suggestions on where to start?  I am a Developer, but I have no experience with Mumps.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am one of the maintainers of [M-Unit](https://github.com/ChristopherEdwards/M-Unit). I used it extensively to run regression tests on M code. M-Unit is relatively easy to use.

There is integration of M-Unit with CMake if you want to get fancy... but that's hard to run and has lots of hardcoded variables. If you are interested in that, take a look at code in the [OSEHRA VistA repository](https://github.com/WorldVistA/VistA)